# Spying Animal Kithain in Animal Form

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming, changeling-20th-anniversary

Pooka and Selkies have a Birthright that allows them to turn into mundane animals. Be they hares or cats or whatever for the Pooka or Seals or Sea Lions for the Selkies (though, technically also walrus), they might appear fully natural... at least there is nothing in the book that hints that they differ in any physical way from their mundane counterparts...

Is there a special way for an enterprising Kithain to spot the Selkie playing with the colony of harbor seals or the Pooka bunny hiding in the pen with the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best guidance I could find might actually be hidden in earlier editions of Changeling:

- Immortal Eyes: The Toybox <sup>1</sup> tells that a roll of Wits + Kenning with difficulty 6 could detect a Selkie in their Seal Shape, which seems both straightforward and logical considering what Kenning is used for.
- Pooka in the 2nd Edition Core Book have the statement "Changelings can't ken the animal form of a pooka in her
  mortal seeming" <sup>2</sup> associated with them, but that doesn't tell about kenning the fae in the animal form.

Interpolating from that, it is a simple Wits + Kenning roll to detect that there *is* a fae, but it takes a little more (like more successes) to figure out if it's a Pooka, Selkie, or some other shape- or skin-changer.

---

1 - Changeling the Dreaming - Immortal Eyes: the Toybox, p.127.
2 - Changeling the Dreaming, 2nd Edition (2000), p.95.